# Is there a way to close a Writer without closing the underlying stream?

Tags: java, sockets, io, outputstream

I have a socket to which I write some character data, and some raw byte data. For the character data, it's easier to use a `PrintWriter`. For the raw byte data, it's easier to write directly to the `OutputStream`. So throughout my code, I have segments like this:

```
Writer writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
writer.write(someText);
...
writer.flush();
// No call to writer.close(), because that would close the underlying stream.
```

As long as I am careful not to write to this `Writer` after beginning to write to the stream in some other way, this is fine. But I would prefer the safety of knowing that I'll get an `IOException` if I accidentally do write to the stream (as I would if I had closed it).

Is there a way to explicitly prevent future writes to a `Writer` without closing its underlying stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply put, no. The way Java io stream classes are written, they always chain close operations. You could of course, create your own writer implementation that overrode this behavior.

Answer (score 12):

Why? `close()` only does two things: (1) flush the writer and (2) call `close()` on the nested writer. If you don't want (2), call `flush()` yourself and don't call `close()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a special class allowing to write both characters and binary data, something like:

```
class CombinedWriter extends Writer {
    private boolean isWritingBinary;
    private Writer mWriter;
    private OutputStream mOutputStream;
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        // flush the writer if necessary
        isWritingBinary = true;
        mOutputStream.write(bytes);
    }
    public void write(String string) {
        // flush if necessary
        isWritingBinary = false;
        mWriter.write(string);
    }
    public void flush() {
        // ...
    }
    public void close() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It may extend or not extend `Writer`; in the latter case, you do not need to override methods not used in your code.

The trick with the writer flush is still there, but it is localized to one class; in addition, if the trick breaks in some future version, the class may be rewritten to eliminate the trick (one will likely need to borrow a portion of code from Android sources).

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use OutputStream for both character and binary data:

```
byte strBin[] = someText.getBytes("UTF-8");
outputStream.write(strBin);
```

Replace "UTF-8" if you want a [different](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) encoding.

Comment: It's better to use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` from `java.nio.charset` package rather than hard coding the name using string literal on java 7+

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking! I had exactly the same problem, and it was easy to solve. From reading your question it sounds like you might be trying to do exactly what I was trying to do, so I wanted to help out by giving the solution that worked for me.

In my case I was trying to write a HTTP response for a jpg, in which case the text header section will be followed by binary data. The stream here is the `OutputStream` of a Java `Socket`.

I was using a `PrintWriter` to write text to the socket stream, but then I needed to write the binary data. There is an easy solution, which works as-is for the case where binary data follows text data, and there is no more text data after the binary data.

Simply open a `Printwriter` on the stream and use the writer to print text into the stream until all the text is written. Then flush the `PrintWriter` to the stream, but don't close it (that closes the underlying stream, which must stay open). Lastly, write the binary data directly to the stream.

At the end you may simply close the `PrintWriter` to close the underlying stream.

If using the class provded below, you would:

1. Construct the `HttpStreamWriterImpl` by providing the `OutputStream` for the underlying `Socket`.
2. Call `writeLine()` repeatedly as needed.
3. Call `writeBinary()` if/as needed.
4. Call `close()` when finished.

Example:

```
public class HttpStreamWriterImpl implements Closeable
{
    private @NotNull OutputStream stream;
    private @NotNull PrintWriter printWriter;

    public HttpStreamWriterImpl(@NotNull OutputStream stream)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.printWriter = new PrintWriter(stream, true, UTF_8);
    }

    public void writeLine(@NotNull String line)
    {
        printWriter.print(line);
        printWriter.print(HTTP_LINE_ENDING);
    }

    public void writeBinary(@NotNull byte[] binaryContent) throws IOException
    {
        printWriter.flush();
        stream.write(binaryContent);
        stream.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```